# selenium - python: inherit web-element class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, inheritance, selenium-webdriver

i want to create my own web element class. IE:

```
class myWebElement(selenium.WebElement):
def __init__(self, element):
    self = element  
def click(self):
   #my custom actions
   super().click()
```

however, on calling super.click(), i get something like: *"object has no _id attribute"*.

can anyone tell me how it can be done?

**p.s**

the idea is wrapping functions to make them more resilient  [try click(), if failed -  scroll to element\make visible, and try click() again, etc]

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. first, in general correct inheritance would look like:

```
class class(parent):
def __init__(self, args...):
  super().__init__(parent_args...)
```

in this case, i couldn't figure out in docs how to initialize a Web-element. but after research:

```
class myElement(WebElement):
def __init__(self, element):
  super().__init__(element._parent, element._id)
```

and walla.

Comment: add `print(element.get_attribute('innerText'))` and `print(self.get_attribute('innerText'))` at the end of `__init__` function. `self` returns `None`

Comment: Checked, and it returns same thing.